# Is curling the fingers considered digit flexion?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology

Is curling the fingers considered finger flexion and straightening the fingers considered finger extension? I feel like this is correct in everyday language, but I am not sure if it is correct in anatomical terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the vertical plane, bending of the fingers is indeed referred to as *flexion*, while straightening is called *extension*. In the horizontal plane, spreading the fingers is called abduction, and approximation is called adduction (Fig. 1).

[image]
<sup>Fig. 1. Finger movements and terminology. source: [US Dept. of Veteran Affairs](http://www.rehab.research.va.gov/jour/11/481/li.html)</sup>